# what exactly is the difference between doing abc.p = undefined and delete abc.p

Tags: javascript, html

I have an object referred to by the variable `abc`

Besides the return value of the expressions, what exactly is the difference between doing `abc.p = undefined` and `delete abc.p`

Answer (score 5):

```
> abc.p = undefined
undefined

> 'p' in abc
true

> delete abc.p
true

> 'p' in abc
false
```

Assigning a member to `undefined` doesn't make the member go away. It still occupies a place in the object (but its value is `undefined`). `delete`-ing it will actually remove the member.

Comment: Also, using `delete` will prevent the property showing up in `for...in` loops whereas setting it to `undefined` will not.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, they serve the same purpose.

```
var abc = {};

abc.p = "hello";
alert(typeof abc.p);//string
delete abc.p;
alert(typeof abc.p);//undefined

abc.p = "hello world";
alert(typeof abc.p);//string
abc.p = undefined;
alert(typeof abc.p);//undefined
```

Here is a detailed explanation on `delete`: [Understanding Delete by Kangax](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)

Answer (score 0):

`abc.p = undefined` will not remove the property, i.e. it's still listed when iterating over the object. `delete abc.p` will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

`abc.p = undefined` will keep the property to the object but its value will be `undefined`.

The `delete abc.p` will remove the property completely from the object.

Comment: @Khangis, the difference is that if you search for the properties of `abc` you will see that the object has a `p` property in the first case, and that `abc` does not have a `p` property in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

One exception is when using "with" statement:

```
abc.p = undefined;
with(abc) {alert(p);} // shows: "undefined"

delete abc.p;
with(abc) {alert(p);} // an error occurs: "ReferenceError: p is not defined"
```